# Inline math in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, inline, displaystyle

I use displaystyle for math expressions in all my documents but I want just the inline style just in the table of contents. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is an integral $\int_{0}^{1}f(t){\rm d}t$}
\section{This is a series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: move `\everymath{\displaystyle}` after `\tableofcontents` ? but `\everymath{\displaystyle}` pretty much destroys inline math typesetting, are you sure you want that?

Comment: Thanks the solution was easy but I didn't find it. Shame on me.

Comment: unrelated but `{\rm d}` should be `\mathrm{d}` (`article` defines `\rm` for legacy compatibility but it has not been defined by default in latex since 1993)

Comment: Off-topic: The notation `\sum_{n\ge1}^{+\infty}` seems to contains some redundancy. I would write either `\sum_{n\ge1}` or `\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a switch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newif\ifinToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\inToCtrue}
\everymath{\ifinToC\else\displaystyle\fi}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is an integral $\int_{0}^{1}f(t){\rm d}t$}
\section{This is a series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$}
\end{document}
```

But maybe it would be better to limit `\displaystyle` to the math inside headings, because inside text, it is ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newif\ifinToC
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\CDS}{\ifinToC\else\displaystyle\fi}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\inToCtrue}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is an integral $\CDS \int_{0}^{1}f(t){\rm d}t$}
Wouldn't it be besser to not have the display style here inside paragraphs
like this, and to use $\int_{0}^{1}f(t){\rm d}t$ here. \blindtext
Because using $\CDS \int_{0}^{1}f(t){\rm d}t$ make the paragraph very
ugly, at least if you have several such formulars inside one paragraph, like
here: $\CDS\sum\limits_{n\ge1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ \blindtext

\section{This is a series $\CDS\sum\limits_{n\ge1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you simply must use `\everymath{\displaystyle}`, I would like to suggest that you use the optional argument of `\section` to instruct LaTeX to typeset the math material in `\textstyle` math mode in the ToC. This approach will also let you make further changes that will benefit the appearance of the document, such as using inline-fraction notation for the ToC entries and `\boldmath` for the section headers themselves.

I would assume that you're already using `\textstyle` directives elsewhere where you want to override the effect of `\everymath{\displaystyle}`, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip % optional: insert a visual separator

\section[The integral $\textstyle\int_0^1 f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$]%
   {\boldmath The integral $\int_0^1 \!f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$}
\dots

\section[The sum $\textstyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}$]%
   {\boldmath The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$}
\dots

\end{document}
```